# Accessing class methods inside another class at same scope

Tags: python, class

Trying to get a work around for getting access to a class method in another class while being inside a class. Code below will probably explain my goal.

```
class Access(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def select(self, value):
        Store.keep(value)

class Store(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.store_value = 0

    def keep(self, value):
        self.store_value = value

x = Access()
y = Store()

x.select(10)

y.store_value
##Want the output of 10
```

Comment: There's no way this can possibly work. How can A know which instance of Store to put the value in? Maybe you should show your actual use case.

Comment: Yes. If you want to have a method for more than one class you can model a super class (inheritance) which can distribute the method to its subclasses. Or maybe an abstract class is what you want. It depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way to do what you want without Access having a reference to a Store object.

The closest thing you can do is

```
class Access(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def select(self, value):
        Store.keep(value)

class Store(object):

    @classmethod
    def keep(cls, value):
        cls.store_value = value

x = Access()
y = Store()

x.select(10)

print y.store_value #will print 10 

#but

z = Store()

print z.store_value #will print 10 too
```

Where `store_value` is shared by all instances of Store.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass an instance to `select` also and use `Store.keep(inst, value)`:

```
class Access(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def select(self, inst, value):
        Store.keep(inst, value)

class Store(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.store_value = 0

    def keep(self, value):
        self.store_value = value

x = Access()
y = Store()

x.select(y, 10)

print(y.store_value) 
10
```